# Is there any way to send binary data with XMLHttpRequest object?

Tags: javascript, binary, xmlhttprequest, send

I'am trying to send binary chunk with XMLHttpRequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var bindata = 0x0f0f;

xhr.open("POST", "binary_reader.php");

xhr.send(bindata);
```

But this approach not works. I've tried to provide **Content-type: application/octet-stream**, **Content-encoding** headers for **xhr** and they don't work either. I am suspect that there is no way to compose request of such kind.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to send a file this way? There are some changes in the level 2 spec that allow blob sending, it depends exactly what you're trying to do though: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-send-method

Comment: No, this is not a file. It's a encoded packet that is supposed to be sent on server. Server, in its turn, responds with packet of similar structure. I understand I can do either way and encode/decode packets when sending/receiving being done with base64, but I try to save CPU time and packet size overhead because of webapp "realtimeness".

Answer (score 4):

`XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary` is obsolete. [Link](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/sendAsBinary)

As [MDN mentioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_typed_arrays_as_binary_data), you can directly send binary typed array:

```
var myArray = new ArrayBuffer(512);
var longInt8View = new Uint8Array(myArray);

// generate some data
for (var i=0; i< longInt8View.length; i++) {
  longInt8View[i] = i % 256;
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("POST", url, false);
xhr.send(myArray);
```

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send binary data using XHR. All you need to do is set the appropriate headers and mime-type, and call the sendAsBinary method instead of the simple send method. For example:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open("POST", url, true);  
// set headers and mime-type appropriately  
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", 741);  
req.sendAsBinary(aBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

W3C has introduced Blob type to XMLHttpRequest in the [latest specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/). Currently I haven't seen any implementation so far but in near future this is definitely the way to download and upload binary data with XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The section "Handling binary data" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) describes how to send and receive binary data via XMLHttpRequest.